# substr_count double for each loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, count, substring

I have a set of tweet text in an array. I am trying to see how many times a particular word occurs in these texts.

But it is not just a single word but an array of words loaded from an external file. For each word the count is required.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$poswords = file('positive.csv');

$array = array("value", "bar", "ACCOMPLISHES", "valveworld", "able I am not bladiebla");
$count = 0;
foreach ($poswords as $posword) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $count += substr_count(strtolower($value), strtolower($posword));
    }
    echo "Word: ".strtolower($posword)."      Count: ".$count."</br>";
}
//return $count;
?>
```

So first I load the list of words. Then I have an array of texts named $array. then I loop between each word and for each word I check if that word occurs in the texts with a second loop.
Then for each loop I echo the count for that word.

When U strtolower($posword) it always results in 0 no mather what I do. When I change it to a single word such as "value" I do get a higher count. Then it just adds with each word + 1 to the count variable.

Anybody can figure out what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

P.S: The end goal is to create a tag cloud out of the occuring words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I don't understand the single `$count` value in your current code if you are attempting to build counts for a tag cloud.  I would think that you would need to get the occurrence count for each word in your `$poswords` array.  You should be able to do that like this:

```
$poswords = file('positive.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// create an array to count your words,
// populated with words as keys and 0 as initial value
$word_counts = array_fill_keys($poswords, 0);

// your array of haystack strings
$array = array("value", "bar", "ACCOMPLISHES", "valveworld", "able I am not bladiebla");

// loop through each haystack string
foreach ($array as $haystack) {
    foreach($poswords as $needle) {    
        $match_count = substr_count(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle));
        $word_counts[$needle] += $match_count;
    }
}
var_dump($word_counts);
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the response. I implemented your way and tested but it still results in 0 fo every word while it should have a hit on one of the words as it is also in the list. The list I am using is: http://www3.nd.edu/~mcdonald/Data/Finance_Word_Lists/LoughranMcDonald_Positive.csv  what could be the problem?

Comment: It could be a whitespace issue. See update for suggestion on trimming the strings in `$poswords` and casting them to lowercase.

Comment: Ahh I had not though of that: Implementing the new code results in this error: strtolower() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given with still zeros. But using the previous code with this change seems to be working: $poswords = file('positive.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

Comment: @EMrulez That is a better approach actually. I will update my answer above for any future readers.